# Sentence in the present tense when the text is in the past tense?

Tags: tense

> ゲームをやめるとグループから外されるんじゃないかといつも不安でした。**不安になった日の翌朝は、友だちにすごく優しくするんです。**
>   そうやって友だちに奉仕して、関係を無理矢理にでもうまくつなごうとしていました。いつの間にか友だちづきあいに疲れてしまっていましたね([source](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/web_tokushu/2018_0919.html?utm_int=tokushu-new_contents_list-items_004))

I don't understand why the past tense isn't used for 優しくする(=>優しくした)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sentence in bold is an example of historical present, as the sentence describes his habitual behavior in the past. It's not to be confused with relative tense [described here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25376/5010). It's hard to logically describe when historical present is employed, but in this specific case, the intention is clear; he used it to emphasize the sentence with vividness and emotion.

See:

- [Why did the author briefly jump to present tense in this article?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23349/5010)
- [Negative present endings translated as past tense](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/53760/5010)
- [i am confusesd as to what historical present tense is, when it is used, etc](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55536/5010)