# What does そうとしてみる mean?

Tags: grammar, song-lyrics

From the song: 金木犀の夜

> 声が聴きたくなって
> 電話番号を思い出**そうとしてみる**

I'm wondering if it can mean "I'll try to remember the phone number, then look (if I remembered)", cause that's what my intuition tells me right now, but I'm asking to be sure if that's eally it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "verb＋て＋みる" and "verb＋(よ)う+とする"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19038/what-is-the-difference-between-verb%ef%bc%8b%e3%81%a6%ef%bc%8b%e3%81%bf%e3%82%8b-and-verb%ef%bc%8b%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%81%a8%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b)

Comment: Not really, as for now, it only seems to me like those 2 constructions are similar, but pretty different in nuances, so i dont really get why would someone use both in a same sentence after each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer is really just an extension of [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19040/7705) as it is applied to your sentence. For further details, please see that answer.

In short, `しようとする` and `してみる` mean very different things - the former means `attempt to X` and the latter corresponds to the English `do X and see`, as in doing something and then reflecting on the result.

Consequently, a very direct translation of `電話番号を思い出そうとしてみる` looks something like `I will try to remember the phone number and see how it goes` where `try to` comes from `思い出そうとする` and `see how it goes` comes from `してみる`.

Incidentally, there's no way to know without more context from the song, but I suspect this is [historical present](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/73870/7705) tense, in which case it's really talking about something that has already happened.